# Why is my provisioning profile unable to be selected?

Tags: iphone, ios-provisioning

Edit: Doh! The reason it was unable to be selected was because the bundle identifier entry in the info.plist actually did contain the extra junk strings mentioned below. For some reason (possibly a carriage return in the string) resulted in the extra characters to be invisible in the info.plist so I didn't know they were still there. I just had to put my cursor at the end of the com.company.app and hold down the delete key to solve to problem.

Hope that helps someone else.

Hi,

- I have an app. In the info.plist I have the bundle identifier as "com.company.app"
- I have created a provision profile with the app identifier as "com.company.app" that is installed.
- Under Project -> Edit project settings -> Code Signing Identity, I can select the provisioning profile correctly however if I right-click the target -> Get Info -> I cannot select the provisioning profile (It is greyed out with the message "Profile does not match Application identifier 'com.company.app FJ33AB3.au.com.company... FJ33AB3.au.com.company.company"

So where could it be getting that extra rubbish (FJ33AB3.au.com.company... etc) from? And any ideas how this can be fixed??

Thanks,

Comment: Is the app ID for your app prefixed with FJ33AB3? The provisioning portal generates that for you when you create the app ID.

Comment: No, that was for an old provisioning profile that I'm no longer using. The new provisioning profile has a different set of numbers/letters. It seems like there is old data remaining somewhere but I don't know where to delete it.

Comment: Maybe you should place your edit in an answer and mark it accepted instead (you'll need to wait 2 days though) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it was unable to be selected was because the bundle identifier entry in the info.plist actually did contain the extra junk strings mentioned below. For some reason (possibly a carriage return in the string) resulted in the extra characters to be invisible in the single line of the info.plist so I didn't know they were still there. I just had to put my cursor at the end of the com.company.app and hold down the delete key to solve to problem.

Hope that helps someone else.